# May Passover matzoh be made from durum wheat flour and then reground as meal for Italian pasta?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, matzah, gebrochts

Italian pasta is generally made from durum wheat (semolina) flour. Wheat is one of the grains from which Passover matzoh can be made. Normally matzoh is baked at high heat from flour and water only, then reground to create matzoh flour or matzoh meal as a source for products kosher for Passover use such as cake or deep-fry breading. Semolina is typically a hard flour not suited for bread at all, leavened or unleavened, and Italian pasta is made only from semolina flour and from water. Used semolina pasta can typically be reground after drying to make semolina pasta again, it is not as good but it is still usable as such.  Is is a legal usage to create a matzoh from water and flour, from a grain that is legal (wheat) but inedible (durum) for bread, but which can then be a kosher for Passover source of Italian pasta?  Or, does the fact that the motzah is inedible and never meant for direct consumption for Passover use invalidate the use (appearance of sin, as matzoh is 'bread of affliction' and any other usage too luxurious)?

Comment: How is this different from a Matza Ball (besides proportions of ingredients)?

Comment: One thing that might need clarification in the question: I read your second-to-last sentence as meaning "Is it physically possible?" and the last as meaning "If so, is it allowed?". Or did the second-to-last mean "Is it allowed?" and the last just repeat that?

Comment: Wouldn't baking the matzah make the wheat unfit for making pasta? (honest question)

Comment: @DoubleAA:  Italian pasta is semolina and water only, extruded or rolled.

Comment: @Daniel Durum wheat can take the punishment of baking and drying and still make "halfway" decent noodles which are while not as elastic, still more than serviceable.

Comment: @eternalsquire Ok... so the only difference between your product and a Matza ball is it's missing the eggs? Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @DoubleAA the question is one of intent.  The intermediate stage, regular motzah, is edible and can be used as such.   Durum motzah would be inedible AS Motzah.  Is the latter invalid motzah?

Comment: @eternalsquire Why would it be inedible? Please clarify that, as well as include all your reasoning, in your post via [edits]. There is no reason I should have to ask these questions to prompt you to include relevant information about the basis of your question in the question post. When you write questions, include that stuff from the outset.

Comment: anyone ever try to eat an uncooked spaghetti noodle?  redried spaghetti noodles are almost as hard! this is common knowledge!

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81756