# Would leavened bread made from matzo meal be kosher for Passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven, matzah

Flour which is wet for 18 or more minutes is considered to be "leavened", and therefore *chametz*.  However, though there's [some disagreement](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/chabad-custom-of-not-allowing-water-to-touch-matzah-on-pesach/15646#15646), this restriction is generally not applied to matzo, or food items made from matzo meal (e.g., matzo ball soup).

Wikipedia [tells me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gebrochts) that this is because:

> ...matzo and its derivatives are neither "leavened" nor "leavenable" and therefore are permissible for consumption during Passover.

---

Matzo meal works [reasonably well](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/16158/passover-rolls-i/) as a flour substitute in some recipes (though see linked question below about whether it would work for traditional leavened bread).

Since matzo meal is apparently considered not to be leavenable, would a traditional, leavened bread made using matzo meal in place of flour be considered kosher for Passover?  If not, why not (and why doesn't the same reasoning apply to matzo ball soup)?

(This now has a [companion question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/80808/can-sufficiently-finely-ground-matzo-meal-substitute-for-flour-in-leavened-bread) about whether such bread would be *practical*.)

Comment: Lots of people make rolls and cakes out of matza meal.  I've never heard of bread, but that might be for practical reasons.  It doesn't tend to cut nicely.

Comment: @Heshy do you think that's an unavoidable consequence of working with matzo, or is it just because most people make matzo meal in a food processor (fairly coarse grind) rather than with a flour mill/quern/etc. that would grind it down to flour consistency (i.e., could you solve the texture problem just by grinding your matzo finer)?

Comment: Seems pretty kosher. I don't know how good it would taste. You can ask on cooking.se about the science here. I don't think the gluten develops right in a matza meal dough.

Comment: @DoubleAA asked!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: @DoubleAA You would seem to be correct. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/80808/can-sufficiently-finely-ground-matzo-meal-substitute-for-flour-in-leavened-bread

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/72979

Comment: I think this is one of the main premises / concerns behind *gebrokhts*.